# While loop skips cin.getline() for C-string

Tags: c++, cin, getline, c-strings

I want to use a while loop to repeatedly ask the user for a line of input with cin.getline() and store the input as a C-string.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const int N = 3;
    char arr[N + 1] = {};
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter " << N << " characters: ";
        std::cin.getline(arr, N + 1, '\n');
    }
}
```

If the user types `abc`, then `arr` contains `a`, `b`, `c`, `\0`, and on the next loop it pauses for the next line of input, as expected.

If the user types `abcd`, then `arr` still contains `a`, `b`, `c`, `\0`, but on the next loop the first element `a`  changes to `\0` and the program never again pauses for the next line of input. It just prints out "Please enter 3 characters: " over and over. Why? How can I get it to pause every time, regardless of the input?

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Olaf for pointing out that I need to reset the failbit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int N = 3;
    char arr[N + 1] = {'\0'};
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Please enter " << N << " characters: ";
        cin.getline(arr, N + 1, '\n');
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, because the [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate#The_failbit) is set, see [`std::basic_istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

> Behaves as UnformattedInputFunction. After constructing and checking the sentry object, extracts characters from *this and stores them in successive locations of the array whose first element is pointed to by s, until any of the following occurs (**tested in the order shown**):
>
> - end of file condition occurs in the input sequence (in which case setstate(eofbit) is executed)
> - the next available character c is the delimiter, as determined by Traits::eq(c, delim). **The delimiter is extracted** (unlike basic_istream::get()) and counted towards gcount(), but is not stored.
> - **count-1 characters have been extracted** (in which case setstate(failbit) is executed).

This means, when more than `N` characters are entered by the user, the delimiter is *not* found and `N+1-1` characters have been extracted.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), the second parameter, `N + 1`, must include the `'\0'` null terminator. So, `abcd` input isn't a valid input because `getline()` needs a size of `5` to store the string as well as `'\0'`.

Comment: I think you're off by one. ```N+1``` must contain the null character, but this is automatically appended to the array. So ```getline(arr, N+1)``` only extracts the first ```N``` characters so there is still room to store the ```'\0'```. In this case, if the input is ```abcd```, it only extracts ```abc``` and then appends the null character. But on the next cycle through the while loop, ```getline``` doesn't pause for input.